# Using Tsung to load test gen_tcp (SSL) with custom binary interface

Tags: erlang, load-testing, tsung

I have a server written in Erlang with a custom binary interface that gets communicated over a TCP socket (SSL-enabled)

I need to be able to load test this server.

Tools like Tsung seem to work well but for interfaces that support HTTP, LDAP, Jabber/XMPP etc. Is it possible to use Tsung in its correct form to interface with my server via a binary interface? Is there a better solution?

Comment: It is possible to write a custom protocol plug-in for your custom binary protocol.  It would be coded in Erlang.  There is no TCP protocol plug-in because this protocol has no concept of what constitutes a request or response.  These are defined by your application protocol, and you need to tell Tsung what these look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a tsung plugin.. Here is an [example](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/Writing_a_Tsung_plugin/).

If I knew more about the specifics of your data, I could help more.

Comment: [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150208112949/http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/Writing_a_Tsung_plugin/) is cached version of tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Tsung but you could use [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) to load test your application using a custom junit test.